# Is it necessary to use __block type specifier for mutable objects altered in blocks?

Tags: objective-c, block

Say map is a NSDictioanry, my understanding is since the address of res does not change in the block we don't need to use __block for it. Is this correct?

```
//__block NSMutableArray *res = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *res = [@[] mutableCopy];
__block NSInteger i = 0;
[map enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSArray *v, BOOL *stop) {
    [res addObject:v];
    i++;
}];
```

By the way I have run the code it works fine.

Comment: Does the compiler complain? Run the code and print `res`. What happens?

Comment: i have run it it works fine

Comment: Then the answer is: No :-) The compiler will tell you if `__block` is missing.

Comment: BTW, there's no real reason to use `[@[] mutableCopy]` — it's no faster than `[NSMutableArray array]`, and is less clear to read.

Answer (score 3):

The `__block` type specifier is only necessary for the storage of mutable items which would normally go on the stack.

Since a block is not guaranteed to be called only within the scope of the method that creates it (this is called escaping), it might need to mutate variables which it references after they've gone away. References to things that go on the stack (like `i` in your example) can become dangling pointers if the block is held onto past the end of the original method or function, so if they are to be mutated, they need to be stored somewhere other than the stack. The `__block` specifier tells the compiler to put the variable in separate storage which will be valid whenever the block is called.

For things which are heap allocated (like `res` above), this is not necessary — since the pointer to the object will not change as long as the object is around (which it should be, since the block will retain it by default), the local storage of the object pointer does not need to be put in alternative storage, and can stay on the stack.

If you'd like to read more on this, the [Blocks and Variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) documentation page has in-depth info on memory management with blocks, and more on the `__block` storage type.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. `__block` is only necessary if you assign (`=` or equivalent) to the variable inside the block, or if you want to block to be able to see assignments to the variable outside the block after the block was created. (This is true regardless of what the variable's type is.)

Here, The variable `i` is assigned to inside the block, with the `++` operator, hence `__block` is necessary. The variable `res` is never assigned to anywhere; the variable `res` is *read from* (not assigned to) inside the block.